# Difficulty Troubleshooting a Misbehaving App

Tags: android

We have a simple app deployed using PhoneGap targeting Android version 2.2 API 8 and up. On the various android emulator's I've setup it works and on all the devices in the office it works....except one and go figure it's the squeaky wheel in the office. So enough noise has been made that I am now tasked with spending time on only one device. I've setup an emulator as close to it as possible. The device is a Motorolla Droid2 Global running 2.3.4. Know right off the bat I can't setup the emulator to 2.3.4 only 2.3.3. I understand 2.3.4 is only a service patch but I'm trying to mimic it as best as possible.

The behavior that it exhibits is that upon opening on this one device it hangs indefinately with a white modal screen and the spinning animation. Of course I can't get the behavior to happen in development. Further everything is self contained so there are no web services etc. involved. So I need advice on how to debug.

My current thought...may not be a good one is to fall back to the 80's and put a message box display after every significant line of code and push the .apk onto her device.

Also since this happens at the very load of the application here is the code...one line.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //super.load( "file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.
JB

Comment: Get some logging in there, borrow the "squeaky" device - and profusely thank the owner for bringing the problem to your attention with a local example, rather than having the report come from an irate remote user.  (If they won't let you touch their device, give your project management the option of renting a similar one for your to test on; there are services that make this quite affordable)

Comment: First user is at home today, but a second user said they have the same problem on their kindle and I have it hooked up to my dev environment now. As for logging do you mean in the app or at the os level. I assume you mean the app.

Comment: Get some logging in your javascript and get it connected through to the logcat log; also get logging in any java functions you call or have added to the phonegap base. Run logcat and see what you get in the way of messages from all levels.  Develop suspicions and set logging traps for them.

Comment: Chris, I saw the error and Googled the answer via LogCat. May seem pretty obvious but I'm pretty new to Android, Eclipse (c# dev), java etc. So If you want reply with an actual post and I'll mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a path towards a solution than an actual solution, but anyway:

Get some logging in your javascript and get it connected through to the logcat log; also get logging in any java functions you call or have added to the phonegap base. Run logcat and see what you get in the way of messages from all levels. Develop suspicions and set logging traps for them.